# Why position inside Adapter is starting again at 0?

Tags: java, android

i have used recyclerview and list from firebase , i tried to test the values inside position it begins to go through each item 1,2,3 but then suddenly the position value reverts back to 0 and getting the text values from the data items already used.,  my Log.i positionAll_ printing is looping, to look like:
0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3

```
 public class StudiumRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StudiumRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    /*region fields*/
    private ArrayList<Stadium> stadiumsList;
    private RecycleViewClicListener listener;
    private float timeinHoures , rate ;
    private MainActivity activity;
    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();

    public StudiumRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Stadium> stadiumsList, RecycleViewClicListener listener, MainActivity activity) {
        this.stadiumsList = stadiumsList;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.timeinHoures = time.getTimeInHoures();
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.stadium_item_row, parent,false);
        StudiumRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new StudiumRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder,int position){
        holder.bind(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return stadiumsList.size();
    }


      /*end metods*/

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private ConstraintLayout not_offer_layout;
        private FrameLayout offer_layout;
        private TextView studiomName, offer_stadium_name, offer_val_txtV;
        private TextView avalibleTextView, offer_available_txt;
        private CircleImageView imageView, offer_statium_imageV;
        private RatingBar ratingBar, offer_statdium_ratingBar;
        private FrameLayout callButton, offer_callButton;
        private ImageView giftImage, offer_giftImg;
        private TextView s_nike_name_xml, offer_stadium_place;
        private ProgressBar row_img_progress;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            not_offer_layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.not_offer_layout_id);
            studiomName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.s_name_xml);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.circleImageView);
            avalibleTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.s_avaliblity_xml);
            ratingBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.appCompatRatingBar);
            s_nike_name_xml = itemView.findViewById(R.id.s_nike_name_xml);
            giftImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gift_image_xml);
            row_img_progress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_img_progress);
            // ----------------------------------- // -------------------
            offer_layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.offer_item_parent);
            offer_available_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.offer_s_avaliblity_xml);
            offer_stadium_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.offer_s_name_xml);
            offer_statium_imageV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.offer_circleImageView);
            offer_stadium_place = itemView.findViewById(R.id.offer_s_nike_name_xml);
            offer_statdium_ratingBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.offer_appCompatRatingBar);
            offer_giftImg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.offer_gift_image_xml);
            offer_val_txtV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.offer_val_txtV_id);
        }

        String _rate = "" ;

        public void bind(final int position){
            String key = stadiumsList.get(position).getKey();
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            Stadium stadium = stadiumsList.get(position);
            // rate = stadium.getRate();
            Log.i("positionAll__  :","" +position);
            Log.i("rateAll__2  :", "" + stadiumsList.get(position).getRate());
            // if(stadium){
            // } else {
            ratingBar.setRating(stadium.getRate());
            if (stadium.getGiftFrom() != null) {
                Log.i("YY", "Yess");
                //offer_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                not_offer_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                offer_stadium_name.setText(stadium.getName());
                offer_stadium_place.setText(stadium.getAreaName());
                offer_statdium_ratingBar.setRating(stadium.getRate());
                // For Stadium Logo Image ........................//
                String temp = stadiumsList.get(position).getLogoLink();
                Picasso.with(activity).load(temp).fit().into(imageView);

                if (stadium.getTimeFrom() <= timeinHoures && timeinHoures <= stadium.getTimeTo()) {
                    avalibleTextView.setText(R.string.avilable);
                } else avalibleTextView.setText(R.string.notavlible);
                callButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.call_button);
                callButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        activity.call(position);
                    }
                });

              offer_val_txtV.setText(stadium.getGiftValue());
              offer_val_txtV.append("% off");
              ratingBar.setRating(stadium.getRate());

            } else {
                Log.i("YY", "Noo");
                offer_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                not_offer_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                studiomName.setText(stadium.getName());
                s_nike_name_xml.setText(stadium.getAreaName());
                String temp = stadiumsList.get(position).getLogoLink();
                 // For Stadium Logo Image
                Picasso.with(activity).load(temp).error(R.drawable.avatar2).into(imageView, new Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {
                                row_img_progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError() {

                            }
                        });
                DrawableRequestBuilder<String> thumbnail = Glide.with(activity).load(temp);
                try {
                    Glide.with(activity.getBaseContext()).load(temp).thumbnail(thumbnail).into(imageView);
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if(stadium.getTimeFrom() <= timeinHoures && timeinHoures <= stadium.getTimeTo()) {
                  offer_available_txt.setText(R.string.avilable);
                } else offer_available_txt.setText(R.string.notavlible);
                callButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.call_button);
                callButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        activity.call(position);
                    }
                });

            }

            Log.i(TAG,stadium.getKey());
            Log.i(TAG,stadium.getName());
            Log.i(TAG,stadium.getAreaName());

            // Log.i("RATSS:----- ", String.valueOf(stadium.getRate()));

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            listener.OnItemClicListener(getAdapterPosition(), stadiumsList.get(getAdapterPosition()), stadiumsList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getIsFree_booking());
        }
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<Stadium> stadiumsList) {
       this.stadiumsList = stadiumsList;
        StudiumRecyclerAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



    public interface RecycleViewClicListener {
        void OnItemClicListener(int position, Stadium stadium_item, String online_book);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the activity in which you've bound the data to recyclerview?